# Modules in Artifactory - What are they?

Tags: devops, artifactory

There's a concept in Artifactory of "Modules". In the UI, when you go to the "Builds" tab, and enter some specific build, you get a list of Module IDs, which is, from what i've seen, just the name of the build.

So when I do this:

```
jfrog rt upload --build-name Kuku --build-number 1 File.bin Repo/path/
```

I get a Build with name "kuku", the number "1", and inside I have a list of Module IDs, with only 1 entry - Kuku, and if I click on it  then I can see the list of artifacts that are part of this build.

So my question is, what are these Modules? How can I add more modules (Or why should I) to a specific build?

Just mention that I'm using a Generic repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module are part of the JFrog [build info](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Build+Integration) [open](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info) integration layer for the CI servers and build tools which is used for capturing build metadata.
Build info can be captured using CI integrations, build tools, the JFrog [CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) or the [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-BUILDS). Once it is published to Artifactory, you can query it using the REST API, [Artifactory Query Language](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language) (AQL) and [GraphQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/GraphQL).
As part of build info, a module is a way to group artifacts which where produced by as build and dependencies which where used when building them. A module, for example, can represent a micro service.

The JFrog CLI, which you are already using, can be used for [collecting build info](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-CollectingBuildInformation).
You can add artifacts when [uploading](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles) them in the following way:

```
jfrog rt upload --build-name Kuku --build-number 1 --module Momo File.bin Repo/path/
```

And dependencies can be added when you are [downloading](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles) them:

```
jfrog rt dl "my-local-repo/yoyo.zip" kuku-dependencies/ --build-name Kuku --build-number 1 --module Momo
```

To publish build info, use the following command:

```
jfrog rt bp kuku 1
```

Comment: So if i got you straight: A build (build name & number) is comprised of modules, which in turn are comprised of Artifacts? In which use case would I want one build to be comprised of several modules? Isn't it correct to separate those to different builds?

Comment: @YoavKlein Indeed the build info model support multi module builds but it does not dictate them. For example, in some cases a monolith application has one build which generates multiple modules while for a micro services architecture you will have separate builds

Comment: Does your above example of downloading the `kuku.bin` as a dependency form kuku/1 build make sense, given that it was originally an artifact of the same kuku/1 build?

Comment: @YoavKlein no, its just for the sake of demonstrating to command you should run. Changed it for clarity